# How to use a Bootstrap Modal to delete in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

Must I add to JavaScript section or not?

HTML

```
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-xl">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h2><b>Shipping</b></h2>
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="add_ship" class="btn btn-success" ><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Add New Shipping</span></a>
                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="search-box">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Name">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Destination</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for shipping in shipping_info %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ shipping.shipping_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ shipping.driver_id.driver_fname }}   {{ shipping.driver_id.driver_lname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ shipping.destination }}</td>
                        <td>{{ shipping.ship_date }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{% url 'edit_shipping' shipping.shipping_id %}" class="edit" ><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                            <a href="{% url 'view_shipping' shipping.shipping_id %}" class="" ><span class="material-icons">
visibility
</span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    
                  
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Delete Modal HTML -->

<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

<div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                <div class="modal-header">                      
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Delete User</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                    
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete these Records?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>This action cannot be undone.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I can delete but it doesn't have modal so I added this but when I add it can't delete.

view

```
def delete_shipping(request,pk):
del_dri = shipping.objects.get(shipping_id=pk)
del_dri.delete()
return redirect('table_shipping')
```

The problem is a funny error in the modal form

Url

```
path("delete_shipping/<str:pk>",views.delete_shipping,name='delete_shipping'),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're tried change input:

```
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
            </div>
```

to:

```
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                <a hrfe= "{% url "delete_shipping" %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete </a>
            </div>
```

?